# QImage.save is too slow

Tags: c++, image, qt

I'm using QT 5.9.2, I wrote the following code to save the image of 25.8Mbytes in png format:

```
auto urlImage = QUrl(QString("%1/ref.png").arg(url.toString()));
qInfo() << QObject::tr("Save image") << urlImage.toLocalFile();
image_.save(urlImage.toLocalFile());
qInfo() << QObject::tr("Done:")<<image_.width()<<"x"<<image_.height();
```

and, the following is the log info:

```
[75432] [17:00:15.175] [+] "Save image" "c:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Models/1/18-07-16-16-03-41/ref.png"
[75432] [17:00:39.538] [+] "Done:" 7296 x 2885
```

the image_ is QImage, the save method took more than 20 seconds! How can I speed up this.

Comment: Are you writing to an old hard-drive (not an SSD)? Is the drive busy with other requests? Is your computer generally busy? Is the drive you write to slow normally?

Comment: Try compiling with `-Os` or `-O2` flag.